# Using Vidyard embedded player inside of Angular

Tags: angular, video, embed

The embed code provided from the Vidyard Portal is like below:

```
<!-- The script tag should live in the head of your page if at all possible -->
<script src="https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<!-- Put this wherever you would like your player to appear -->
<img
  style="max-width: 100%;"
  class="vidyard-player-embed"
  src="https://play.vidyard.com/Cse5Fqy1CpUWqYdtikKrFy.jpg"
  data-uuid="Cse5Fqy1CpUWqYdtikKrFy"
  data-v="4"
  data-type="inline"
/>
```

I need to integrate this in Angular (2 & above) which is in typescript. I tried few ways, I can see only image rather than video.
If someone can help out, it would be great!!